iOS notifications not being scheduled
I'm building an app to help people reduce smoking/vaping. The user can set up how often they would like to smoke, for how long, during what hours and on what days of the week to enforce this schedule.
So the inputs are:

Every X hours & Y minutes
for Z minutes
from H1 hour to H2 hour
on D[ ] days.

(i.e. I can smoke every 2 hours and 30 minutes, for 5 minutes, on Tuesdays and Thursdays).
I take these inputs and create a schedule of notifications to send the user. I then iterate over this schedule and use scheduleNotificationAsync to create a notification for each start/stop event.
For some reason, the resulting notifications are not correct.
Are there any known limitations with the scheduleNotificationAsync in the expo-notifications package or with iOS notifications in general? I am iterating over a list of notifications to send but not all of the notifications are being scheduled.
I iterated over a list of of 198 items but only 64 notifications are scheduled. I have verified the for loop is executing correctly and the scheduleNotificationAsync function is being called 198 times.

Upon further research, it looks like iOS limits each app to a maximum of 64 scheduled notifications.
